# How to set path to public in Rails 2.2.3 Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to get a local instance up of an existing rails application.  It is built on Rails 2.2.3.  I keep getting errors that seem to me like I need to set the path to the public directory.  When I run "scripts/server" and request pages, I get these errors:

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/favicon.ico" with {:method=>:get}):
...

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/stylesheets/cache/xxx.css" with {:method=>:get}):

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches "/javascripts/cache/xxx.js" with {:method=>:get}):

How do I set the path to public?  Could this have something to do with setting "RAILS_ROOT"?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have those files and/or directories in RAILS_ROOT/public? Based on the above it looks like you've got some sort of cache implementation for assets, what are you using? You are getting a RoutingError because the server can't find the files in the public directory and thus the request is passed on to routing.

Comment: Yes, they are all in RAILS_ROOT/public.  It is as if it doesn't know what RAILS_ROOT is or something.

Comment: When I open the console and evaluate RAILS_ROOT, it is correct.

Comment: REQUEST_URI"=>"http://0.0.0.0:3000/ApplicationName/stylesheets/cache/bundle.css?1295300650"

When I paste this into the browser, it breaks, but when I request:
"http://0.0.0.0:3000/stylesheets/cache/bundle.css?1295300650" (without ApplicationName), it works just fine.  

RAILS_ROOT is exactly correct when I run script console.  What can I change so that the framework will not look for css and javascript in ApplicationName/stylesheets, but in just stylesheets?

Comment: Do you fixed this problem? If yes, could you tell me how?

Answer (score 2):

Check that in `config/environments/{development,test,production}.rb`, `serve_static_assets` is set to true.  Otherwise, Rails will not serve the assets in `/public`.

Note that in production, you should likely have Apache or whatever web server you use serve those assets.  Running it through Rails proper is an unnecessary slow down.

Comment: I added:

config.serve_static_assets = true


and got the following error message:


=> Rails 2.3.4 application starting on http://0.0.0.0:3000
/home/XXX/Applications/XXX/config/environments/development.rb:17:in `load_environment': undefined method `serve_static_assets=' for #<Rails::Configuration:0xb6c2ee74> (NoMethodError)
 from ./script/../config/../vendor/rails/railties/lib/initializer.rb:386:in `load_environment'

Comment: I also read that serve_static_assets should default to true in all of the environments except production.  Any idea why explicitly setting it is getting me an error?